# Zsh — more intelligent autocorrection

Tags: shell, zsh

Is it possible to make Zsh stop trying to correct arguments that are not meant to be files with files from the current directory without turning off correction completely or limiting it to `setopt CORRECT` (only correct the command)?

For example, when `CORRECT_ALL` is set with `setopt`, this happens:

```
 gris@arefiev: ~% cd srcc 
change srcc to src-nyae? n
```

So far, good (argument to `cd` should be a file).  However,

```
 gris@arefiev: ~% man zile
change zile to .zile-nyae?
```

What?  I would expect it to correct `zile` to `.zile` when `man` is called with `-C` option.  It also tries to correct host parameters of `ssh`, first arguments to `sudo` etc which gets really annoying.

I have to resort to a crutch: set `alias man='nocorrect man'` etc etc, for every affected command, but clearly it's not the best solution.  I also don't like `CORRECT` and would prefer the crutch plus `CORRECT_ALL` to just `CORRECT`.

Zsh is `zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`, Debian sid.

**Update**: here is my `.zshrc` http://pastebin.com/67mykgRv

Comment: Have you loaded `compinit` in your `.zshrc`?

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman: Yes.  Completion is working correctly.

Comment: Can you post your .zshrc as an update?

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman: http://pastebin.com/67mykgRv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zsh comes with a large set of completions but a smaller set of corrections. There are many commands for which completion is useful but not correction; for example, it's useful to complete arguments to `mkdir` (to create directories inside existing directories) but not to correct them. The `correct_all` option is very harsh, as it turns on correction everywhere; unfortunately, there is no option to correct only when a set of correct inputs is supplied.

You can customize the corrections for a given command by setting the [`corrections`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-corrections_002c-completion-tag) tag, and customize whether to perform correction by making [`_correct`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fcorrect) part of the [`matcher-list`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002dlist_002c-completion-style) or not. These are set with the [`zstyle`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzutil-Module) builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Well, I guess I'll have to resort to `nocorrect` because adjusting correction tags with `zstyle` is still done per-command, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are missing something in your distribution. Most ZSH implementations come with a large collection of pre-configured completion settings for ZSH that intelligently complete based on the command and argument position. For example on my system there is a *zsh-completions* package. When installed and properly loaded, `man` completes only with things found in the man pages not with files, `ssh` only with host names, `ssh -l` would complete with system usernames, but after `ssh -l caleb` would then return to completing with host names, etc.

You should look into what zsh packages are available and whether you are loading the default configurations properly. You should not have to setup a bunch of manual over-rides for standard commands such as you list in your question.

Comment: Completion of args works: `gris@arefiev: ~% man <tab>` yields `zsh: do you wish to see all 11200 possibilities (5601 lines)?` (number of binaries).  I am concerned with correction, not completion.  It seems like they don't work together.

Comment: @MischaArefiev: I see your point, and you're right I was on a little different track here. At the same time, my shell behaves differently than yours in the area of autocorrect as well, and I have not configured a bunch of individual over-rides. I can't put my finger on what is different in my setup.

Comment: what version of Zsh are you running?

Comment: Last I looked it was 4.3 something but point releases are frequent and this behavior has been consistent for me for quite some time, do I would suspect configuration, but version...

Comment: The problem here is with correction options, not completion.